# jQuery : On load show all divs, on click hide all except this

Tags: jquery

I.ve been working all night to get this function to work, but i'm too much a noob i think :)

I've got a list of checkboxes and a list of div's with corresponding class/id names.

I'd like to have all div's showed on page load and when a user selects one or multiple checkboxes hide the ones not selected.

Anyone can help me out here??

So far I've got the following script :

```
$('.brand').change(function() {
        $('li.merk').not('li#m_' + $(this).attr('id') + '').toggle();

});change();

<input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Gazelle" />
<input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Batavus" />
<input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Trek" />
<input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="KogaMiyata" />


<li class="merk" id="m_Gazelle" style="display:block;">
Gazelle
</li>

<li class="merk" id="m_Batavus" style="display:block;">
Batavus
</li>

<li class="merk" id="m_Trek" style="display:block;">
Trek
</li>

<li class="merk" id="m_KogaMiyata" style="display:block;">
KogaMiyata
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PbZRF/

SOLVED : user m90 did the trick for me, my updated code = @ http://jsfiddle.net/PbZRF/27/

```
$('.brand').on('change',function() {

        $checked = $('.brand:checked'); //perform selection only once

        if ($checked.length){ //checks if there are checked elements at all
           $('.merk').hide(); //hide all
           $checked.each(function(){
               $('li#m_' + $(this).attr('id') + '').show(); //show only the items with corresponding checkboxes
           });
        } else { //no checked elements
           $('.merk').show(); //show all
        }

    });

    <input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Gazelle" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Batavus" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Trek" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="KogaMiyata" />


    <li class="merk" id="m_Gazelle" style="display:block;">
    Gazelle
    </li>

    <li class="merk" id="m_Batavus" style="display:block;">
    Batavus
    </li>

    <li class="merk" id="m_Trek" style="display:block;">
    Trek
    </li>

    <li class="merk" id="m_KogaMiyata" style="display:block;">
    KogaMiyata
    </li>
```

Comment: it seems to work correctly to me. What more you need?

Comment: @uDaY Try checking more than one box.

Comment: Just change your `<li>` to `<div>` and you've got what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `:checked`-pseudoclass to do it a little something like this:

```
$('.brand').on('change',function() {
    $('.merk').hide(); //hide all
    $('.brand:checked').each(function(){
        $('li#m_' + $(this).attr('id') + '').show(); //show only the items with corresponding checkboxes
    });

});​
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/PbZRF/16/

**EDIT**: Responding to your comment you can just check the `.length` of the `$('.brand:checked')` selection and "take measures" in case it returns 0 / is *falsy*:

```
$('.brand').on('change',function() {

    $checked = $('.brand:checked'); //perform selection only once, otherwise you'll get snarky comments around here :P - also best practice, so do it

    if ($checked.length){ //checks if there are checked elements at all
       $('.merk').hide(); //hide all
       $checked.each(function(){
           $('li#m_' + $(this).attr('id')).show(); //show only the items with corresponding checkboxes
       });
    } else { //no checked elements
       $('.merk').show(); //show all
    }

});​
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/PbZRF/27/

Comment: Wow! That's what I'm looking for, except, when i deselect all checkboxes i'd like to have the div's visible again, is this easy to achieve??

Comment: @JoeyvanBilsen Does this mean I'll be going to heaven?

Comment: Most definitely!! I'll tell God to hold a seat for you!!

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder so you still get the snarky comments :P - see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126680/181841 (you are right btw)

Comment: Haha m90, fair enough. Didn't mean to be snarky!

Comment: Whaha, nice post @m90, nice snarky comment Interstellar_Coder, holding a seat for the Interstellar Coder too :)

Comment: @m90 , i'm dealing with another issue at the moment :( I'm implementing this function on a page that also holds Mootools, so I have to change the '$' signs into 'jQuery'. When i do so, I get an error 'jQuery(".brand").on is not a function'... Do you know a way to solve this?

Comment: @m90 , you will be still going to heaven though ;)

Comment: @m90, got it working in jsfiddle, but i keep getting the error on my site, you have a clue what i could be?

Comment: @JoeyvanBilsen That's actually a pretty common problem so a quick search on 'jquery mootools' on SO should help you. In case not please open another question.

Comment: Thnx, I already did, but I can't get it to work.. :( Will open another question!!

Comment: @m90, I'd had to change '$('.brand').on('change',function() {' into 'jQuery('.brand').change(function() {' Thanks a lot for your time anyways!!

Answer (score 1):

Problem: you're using `.toggle()` with multiple checkboxes. So if checkboxes one and two are checked, then divs two and one are toggled once, while divs three and four are toggled twice -- giving you the opposite result from what you desired.

Try this. It uses a Boolean argument for `.toggle()` and an `.each` loop to get the desired result.

```
$('.brand').change(function() {
    $('.brand').each(function() {
        $('li.merk[id="m_' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').toggle(!$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PbZRF/22/

Or, if you want them hidden when not checked and shown when checked:

```
$('li.merk').hide();

$('.brand').change(function() {
    $('.brand').each(function() {
        $('li.merk[id="m_' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PbZRF/25/

Answer (score 0):

well logically onload all boxes need to be checked, so the divs are displayed:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Gazelle" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Batavus" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Trek" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="KogaMiyata" checked="checked" />
```

then all you need is:

```
$('.brand').change(function() {
        $('li#m_' + $(this).attr('id')).toggle();

});​
```

did i understand you correctly?

Comment: Wow!! That almost did it, but i'd like to have the checkboxes unchecked. I want to use this script on a product page and dynamically let users sort on brand, is there some way to achieve this??

Comment: yes, look below for **m90** answer using `hide()` and `show()`

Comment: thanx for your quick reply. I've tried the example of m90, but when i deselect all checkboxes the divs remain hidden, i'd like to see them visible when deselecting all boxes... :(

Comment: m90 helped me figure this out already!! thnx a whole bunch for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Your example worked for me, unless I selected multiple checkboxes. If you only want one option selected, I would suggest using a radio button rather than a checkbox, but if you want multiple selections, I've amended your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/awEWN/4/

```
$('.brand').click(function() {
    $('li.merk').hide();
    $('input.brand:checked').each(function() {
        $('li#m_'+$(this).attr('id')).toggle();
    });
});
```

Basically, it hides the all of the li elements, finds all the checkboxes that have been checked and shows them.

Comment: It's always preferable to put your code in your answer, in addition to a jsFiddle. That way, if the other site goes down or disappears altogether, your answer is still useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.brand').change(function() {
    $('.merk').show(); 
    var $unchecked = $('.brand:not(:checked)'); 

    /* Only hide divs when not all checkeboxes are unchecked  */ 
    if( $unchecked.length !== 4 )
        $unchecked.each(function(){ $('#m_'+this.id).hide(); });             
   });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PbZRF/28/